# Cost of table storage and retrieval

Tags: cleos

I understand that there is a cost to storing data in table, my questions is how to estimate the cost.

```
{"key": "3773036822876127234",
"first_name": "bob",
"last_name": "smith",
"street": "123 My St",
"city": "Big City",
"state": "CA"}
```

The structure above is 131 bytes, names and address may vary in length and I could limit the length to max if needed. So is this examples cost 131 bytes which today is 0.0125 EOS, I calculated this by entering 0.131 KB into the [ram calculator](https://bloks.io/)

Is it correct that the cost of retrieving the record is nothing? Does it cost anything to call a contract that searches the table and returns a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only bytes you store, but the size of index will be charged. Every row in multi_index will consume 112 bytes by default (for primary index) + actual data size (113 bytes in your case). You need to buy 225 bytes before storing your data.
Moreover, if you add secondary indices by adding `eosio::indexed_by` to your multi_index typedef, it will charge more ram per each row.

Comment: In the example above im using key as the primary index and the first and last name are also indexed, could you show me how to calculate this?

Comment: What type of index do you use for first name and last name? Only five types (uint64_t, uint128_t, checksum256, double, long double) are allowed in secondary index and RAM usage will vary depending on what type of index you add.

Comment: I dont know enough about converting text to numbers to answer this, I guess a max name length could be 30 characters, what happens when this becomes numbers?

Comment: You can use checksum256 (for storing 32-byte binary) type then. Each checksum256 index consume 160 bytes, so you'll need about 545 bytes per row.

Comment: Where can i learn how many bytes the other types can store?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean `how many bytes the other types can store`, but the five types for secondary index are `uint64_t`(8), `uint128_t`(16), `checksum256`(32), `double`(8) and `long double`(16).

You can find related information from the next links:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/master/libraries/eosiolib/contracts/eosio/multi_index.hpp#L299-L333

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/contract_table_objects.hpp#L123-L143

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/contract_table_objects.hpp#L244-L287